# TableView makes multiple copies of same label, swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

For some reason, my cell titles keep duplicating. Here's the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.contactNumberLabel.text = allNumbers[indexPath.row]

    // App downloads confirmedContactList from server
    // Before data is downloaded confirmedContactList is empty and 'for in' loop crashes app.
    if confirmedContactList != new {

        // Title should appear only in cells where arrays allNumbers and confirmedContactList are identical
        for n in 0..<self.allNumbers.count {
            for k in 0..<self.confirmedContactList.count {
                if self.allNumbers[n] == self.confirmedContactList[k]{
                    cell.nameLabel.text = "This Title Keeps Duplicating"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Basically, there are two arrays containing telephone numbers, if contact number displayed in cell exist in `confirmedContactList` then `cell.nameLabel` should say something specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called for already displayed indexPaths, the `nameLabel` text is not set to a default value.

If the previously used value passed the confirmedContactList test, then you will see the title even if the new value doesn't pass the test.

Just add a line and you'll be fine :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.contactNumberLabel.text = allNumbers[indexPath.row]

    // reset the label
    cell.nameLabel.text = ""

    // App downloads confirmedContactList from server
    // Before data is downloaded confirmedContactList is empty and 'for in' loop crashes app.
    if confirmedContactList != new {

        // Title should appear only in cells where arrays allNumbers and     confirmedContactList are identical
        for n in 0..<self.allNumbers.count {
            for k in 0..<self.confirmedContactList.count {
                if self.allNumbers[n] == self.confirmedContactList[k]{
                    cell.nameLabel.text = "This Title Keeps Duplicating"
                }
            }
        }
   }
    return cell
}
```